# Loading style from resource on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, delphi, c++builder, firemonkey

Using Firemonkey (FMX) in C++ Builder XE6, I am attempting to load a style in my project's cpp file.

Just before

```
Application->Initialize ()
```

I have

```cpp
Fmx::Types::TFmxObject *style;
style = TStyleStreaming::LoadFromResource((unsigned int)HInstance, L"MacJet", RT_RCDATA);
TStyleManager::SetStyle (style);
```

where the style named MacJet has been loaded as a resource into the project at design time.

When I activate Win32 as the target platform, this runs fine, and the style shows properly in the application.

When I activate Mac OS X, however, I get an error on the style = ... line, stating

"Exception class SIGSEGV (11)."

When I remove the three lines above and run on Mac, the program loads up.

I'm new to cross-platform development, any ideas what is causing this error?

Comment: Why did you cast `HInstance` to `unsigned int`? Is it possible for you to debug the FMX code and step through the `LoadFromResource` function as it executes?

Comment: I am casting from HInstance to unsigned int because of the code sample here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Working_with_Native_and_Custom_FireMonkey_Styles , which does that when setting a style from a resource in the C++ sample.

Comment: When I debug, the error message occurs immediately after tracing into that line or trying to step over it.

Comment: Trying it without the unsigned int cast on the HInstance doesn't seem to change the error.

Comment: Did you build with debug DCUs? Still, why are you casting? It's is clearly wrong and will break in an x64 build.

Comment: Under Tools > Environment Options > Delphi Options > Library, selecting OS X, the Debug DCU Path is set. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I've never done it for osx though so don't know if it applies there.

Comment: Regarding the unsigned int cast, removing the cast in the Win32 build causes an error (Cannot convert 'HINSTANCE__ *' to 'unsigned int'.)

Comment: That's really odd. `SysInit.HInstance` is declared as `HINST`. And `LoadFromResource` receives `HINST`. Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround solution: instead of using a resource and loading the style before the application initialized, I added a TStyleBook to the application's main form, added the style to the stylebook at design time, and then called TStyleManager::SetStyle () passing in the stylebook's Style property to set the application's style on the main form's Create event.