# Access Violation while trying to load FMX style from resources

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, firemonkey-style

I'm trying to load a style resource using this code:

```
var
  Style: TFmxObject = nil;

begin
{$IFDEF IOS}
  Style := TStyleStreaming.LoadFromResource(HInstance, 'iphonestyle', RT_RCDATA); // access violation :(
{$ENDIF}
  if Assigned(Style) then
    TStyleManager.SetStyle(Style);
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmLogIn, frmLogIn);
  Application.Run;

end.
```

But I'm getting an access violation on `LoadFromResource` line. I've added the `.style` file to my project using `Project\Resources and Images...` menu item. Any ideas on what's causing AV?

Comment: That looks like a firemonkey issue. Take a look at this topic for the additional info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741597/loading-style-from-resource-on-mac-os-x

Comment: @Ari0nhh Well, I am unable to use StyleBooks as suggested in that question. Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840341/fmx-style-issue-with-modal-forms?noredirect=1#comment44086413_27840341

Comment: That's as maybe, but it's the exact same question

Comment: Why do you want to load it from recourse rather then put it in a stylebook component and then load it? Also have you added the file for all configurations(Debug/Release) in the project deployment?

Comment: @Remi Because I don't want to link every form's `StyleBook` property.

Comment: @iManBiglari try to add the file using the deployment and add it for all configurations. Then load it using TPath.GetDocumentsPath +filename

Comment: don't forget to have the permissions read and write from storage

Comment: @Remi I get this AV on Windows :(. Haven't tried other platforms yet

Comment: @iManBiglari you can't load iOS styles on any other platform than on iOS it self.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, and it seems that on iOS (at least), style streams are read differently than on Win32. I haven't narrowed it down as to why, just yet. The result is however that if an image resource referred to by the styles appears *after* the styles in question, it blows up. Moving the image resource to the beginning of the style file resolves the issue.